# Why does the site appear to actively impede use of Internet Explorer 11, instead of gracefully degrading?

Tags: discussion, browser-support

Forgive me if I'm looking at this wrong, but this seems to be the case as far as I can tell...

I have IE 11 as a default browser on one of my machines. I understand that SO doesn't support this version. Fine, I'm totally cool with that (in fact I'm a web developer myself and FULLY support this decision). But in the area where it lays out what browsers it does support it doesn't say anything about going out of their way "not" to support any browser... in fact it really appears as though, if it's not a "supported" browser, that the browser may or may not work depending on its implementation.

My experience, however, is that in IE 11 no matter what action I take it simply moves me back to the message at the top of the page stating that IE 11 is not supported. Literally ANY ACTION I take does this.

So it doesn't appear to allow IE 11 to do the best it can but rather it seems to actively prevent it from working. Am I wrong here? Or is this really intentional?

Comment: I just tried IE 11.592.18362.0, and could not recreate your issue. I can browse Stack Overflow fine as long as I just ignore the ugly "Sorry, we no longer support Internet Explorer" banner. Might you have some sort of caching issue?

Comment: Sounds like the page hasn't loaded properly. Are you using any script or ad blocker?

Comment: They are moving the sites ancient code base to use modern specifications: html5, CSS3. From those established specs the supported browser subset is determined. See also: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/322637/maybe-its-time-to-formally-drop-support-for-ie-11

Comment: It appears to "actively" (obviously nobody has `if (user.browser === 'IE11') explode()` written here) impede because IE11 is mostly sunsetted technology. Companies don't support it, and if they used to, this means they abruptly stopped supporting it. This can appear more harmful to users who still participate (though as a developer, i don't know why it's your default browser. Upgrade your life, IE11 is over, time to move on :)

Answer (score 6):

If you're not supporting a browser, you're not intentionally going out of your way to make it a better experience.

To be fair it should just redirect you to a download link for a supported browser if you're using something unsupported, but I wouldn't *expect* that the behavior of the site on an unsupported browser to be "gracefully" degraded.

Think about it like this - if your browser doesn't support something like SVG, then you're going to have to also have the assets which the SVGs also covered, meaning more resources to support... **all for a browser that you're not supporting**.  Or more commonly, if you're dealing with a tricky piece of CSS (like for responsive layouts), then you've got to add either a browser-specific tweak or add some JavaScript shim to gloss over the issue - both things that a developer needs to support **for a browser that's not being supported**.

Maybe an option would be to just redirect someone to a supported browser when they load the site on something truly ancient?

Comment: Is IE 11 "truly ancient" now?

Comment: @CodyGray:  Having had to deal with IE11 issues *briefly* on a major student portal project before exposing the analytics that revealed that of a 60,000 student population, maybe 60 students used IE11 at some point over the last six months, then yeah, I'm considering it ancient.  I'm also scarred from having to support IE5 on order forms, and having to deal with general IE quirks and other oddities that make it just *not* spec compliant.  It belongs in a museum, not running on your desktop.

Comment: I wish I could just give up on everything that has quirks and not spec compliant. :-( Your sample of students is probably biased, considering that students often purchase (or have purchased for them) nice, new computers to start school, so they're rarely more than 3-4 years out of date.

Comment: @CodyGray yes, essentially it's ancient. End of mainstream support for IE11 is set to *this year*. The end of extended support (so, security patches only) would be in 5 years time. It's actively in the process of retirement. That's on top of the heavy push from Microsoft over the last few years to get people to switch to Edge.

Comment: I wish IE11 was truly ancient for me. But I work on systems that route health care traffic and... IE11 is still heavily used in that field at least in my corner of Europe. It's merely in the "going to be EOL" phase for me, which means that it'll probably take another few years before the browser stops breathing down my neck.

Comment: ___Microsoft___ is dropping support for IE soon. What more is there to be said? The browser is ancient, broken, and frankly, a liability if you're still using it.

Comment: @Gimby look, I feel your pain. My job also has to support IE11 because a client uses a single-sign-on solution that only works through that browser... But nowadays IE11 support is more of an edge-case (heh...). Usually you need good justification to *support it*, as opposed to need a justification *not to*. And it's usually just IE11 which isn't even that bad overall. The situation has really advanced from some years ago when you'd have to support way lower versions of IE. At my last job, we had to support IE8+ and we fought tooth and nail to negotiate *not* supporting IE7.

Comment: @Cerbrus so they still support it **now**.